# How to get a terminal general auto-complete function?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, auto-complete

I'm new in macOS and I'm using macOS Sierra,

In my Ubuntu and other Linux-based system, terminal has an auto-complete that helps to complete commands and their options.

For example for `wget` and other commands, in additional to command completion, after pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> 2 times, it lists all command options (if any), or in `sudo w` it list all commands start with **w**

[image: Ubuntu terminal auto-compelete]

But on my Mac, it just complete first commands and don't help for options or second part of command like **whoami** in `sudo whoami`,

I mean it don't show a list of all command that start with `who` after pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> 2 times in `sudo who`

[[image: 2]]

I found some Scripts for `git` options at https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/completion/ , but I want something that do this for all commands and applications.

Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Mark](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/237) said, [`bash-completion`](https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion/wiki/Install-Bash-git-completion) package adds this functionality to terminal.

Comment: Not to `Terminal` but more fundamentally to `bash`.

Answer (score 2):

The completion function is neither coming from any `Terminal` application or the OS on which you work: MacOS X, Linux…

This function is provided by your shell. To check which one is providing you the completion function you like, just get which shell you are using on Linux with:

```
echo ${SHELL}
```

Then change your login shell on MacOS X with:

```
chsh -s /bin/my_preferred_shell
```

to use the one which is performing the completion function you want.

Check that this shell exists and is executable, and read the documentation of `chsh`:

```
ls -ld /bin/my_preferred_shell

man chsh
```

To test it without risk, don't restart your session, just open a new Terminal. In case of error, you will be able to run `chsh` once more.

From shells I used, `bash` and `zsh` are providing many levels of this kind of completion. If you choose `bash` I advise to install your own one from your preferred package manager ( `Homebrew`, `MacPorts`… ).

Comment: Thanks, so, which shell supports this functionality?I'm using **bash**

Comment: Run this command on the environment you'd like to have, not the one you don't like :).

Comment: The function is not usually in the plain shell but in extra packages look for bash_completion for example

Comment: Also note that the Apple supplied bash is very old and I suspect many completions won't work - either use the new default shell zsh or install a shell from a package manager or source.

Comment: @mmmmmm : The `bash` coming with MacOS is rotten with uncorrected bugs! Avoid it!